# SQL Server: simulate full-text search - other ways to do similar searches

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I created full-text catalog and tried creating full-text index but any ways I tried, it failed. well I contacted my web hosting support for help and learned that they have not installed that feature.

Now I should somehow simulate full-text search. what I want to do is, to search multiple number of words in a text. I know some ways to do it, but the performance is my concern.

```
select * 
from messages 
where msgbody like '%word1%' 
  and msgbody like '%word2%' 
  and ... 
  and msgbody like '%wordn%'
```

The other way I have thought of (as my search is only `and` type and there is no `or`) is to search one word and then search the second word in the results of the first search and 3rd search in the results of second search and so on. but this also doesn't look like a good choice.

Comment: Since you're searching with `LIKE '%.....%'` - performance **will** be horribly bad, since SQL Server won't be able to use any indices that might exist....

Comment: @marc_s thats exactly why i'm looking for another way. the other way I have thought of (as my search is only and type not or) is to search one word and then search the second word in the results of the first search and 3rd search in the results of second seach and so on. but this also doesn't look like a good choice

Comment: if `like '%word1%'` is unacceptably bad and you can't get FTS installed or move to a host that has installed it then you would need to roll your own by parsing out the individual words and indexing those against the `messageid`.

Comment: @MartinSmith can you please provide the code, how can I do that?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani - Haven't got any handy. I seem to remember Dot Net Nuke does something similar to this.

Comment: I found some modules but they are not free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're determined *not* to find new hosting (don't blame you) you could use something like `String.Split()` to give you an array (splitting on the space character).  You'd then add all of those strings to a "words" table or something of the sort.  It'd be more referentially proper to build a single "words" table & a linking table, something like this:

```
create table TheWords
    (
    TheWord NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT PKC_TheWords
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( TheWord ) ,
    TheWordID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    )

create table WordsInMsgBody
    (
    MsgBodyID INT NOT NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT FK_MsgBodyID@WordsInBody
        FOREIGN KEY ( MsgBodyID )
        REFERENCES dbo.MsgBody ( MsgBodyID ) ,
    TheWordID INT NOT NULL ,
        CONSTRAINT FK_TheWordID@WordsInBody
        FOREIGN KEY ( TheWordID )
        REFERENCES dbo.TheWords ( TheWordID ) ,
        CONSTRAINT PKC_WordsInBody
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( MsgBodyID , TheWordID )
    )
```

The final constraint ( PKC_WordsInBody ) could be omitted if you're interested in how *many* of a particular word was included in a message.  If you're not, make it the primary key & only insert a single instance of a word into the linking table.

You're going to have to do some work, though, to implement this - it's going to take work to parse apart the message body, insert words which have never been seen before, and insert records into the linking table.